# Overloading string() operator

Tags: c++

I have an assignment that my teacher has told us to use this in the .h file:

```
    operator string();
```

and we can not deviate from it in any way.

So in my .cpp file I have:

```
   Currency::operator string(){
 stringstream output;
 output<<"$";
 output<<dollars;//Why does this return garbage for money1+money2??
 output<<".";
 output<<cents;
 string outputstring = output.str();
 return outputstring;
   }
```

But when I do `string(money1+money2)` it returns garbage, it works fine when I just do 'string(money1)`.  I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

Any help will be great.

Here is my overloaded + operator code:

```
Currency& Currency::operator+(const Currency &rhs){
Currency temp;
temp.dollars = dollars + rhs.dollars;
temp.cents = cents + rhs.cents;
temp.simplify();
return temp;
}
```

**Notes:**  I have run the debugger and there is no issue with the overloaded + operator; it returns what it should.

Comment: Your error probably lies in your `operator+`, not in `operator string`.

Comment: It is possible that your problem is in the code you *didn't* show us. Please create a minimal, **complete** sample program and copy-paste that here. In the process, you may find the bug yourself. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: Just because `operator+` *appears* to return the expected value doesn't mean it's *correct*. Especially with C++.

Comment: I have added the overloaded + code here.

Comment: Your teacher is wrong to forbid you to change that line.  It should be `operator string() const;`

Comment: @Ben Voigt, I got what my teacher said messed up.  So, I was wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Here is my overloaded + operator code:

You are returning a local variable by reference. **Never do this.**

You should be returning it by value:

```
Currency Currency::operator+(const Currency &rhs)
```

Comment: Thanks, I I got got my professor's instructions messed up.  I thought he had it as I originally had it, but I was mistaken.  I have fixed it now and the bug is fixed.